# Chrome versus Edge Javascript differences

Tags: google-chrome, microsoft-edge, v8, difference, javascript-engine

From time to time i get Javascript Files (created by use of Adobe Animate) that crashes in either chrome or edge. In some cases these files crash only in chrome, in some cases they crash only in edge. Its always `RangeError: "Maximum call stack size exceeded"`.

This behaviour is very good reproduceable and does not occur by random.

I checked v8 versions by "chrome://version/" and both browsers have the same version (V8 9.7.106.18)

I wonder how this can be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(V8 developer here.)

Without knowing more about what those apps are doing, it's hard to be sure. There are a few factors at play:

- The maximum size of the stack in bytes. Operating systems set an upper bound on this, beyond which they'd kill the process. To avoid that, V8 sets its own limit a little under what it estimates the OS limit would be. I wouldn't expect any differences in this regard when the V8 version is the same; however I don't know whether Edge overrides the default value with a different limit.
- The size of each stack frame. This, too, should be the same as long as the V8 version is the same. It could be affected by optimization decisions (optimized code for a given function can use more or less stack space than unoptimized code for the same function), but I'd be surprised if Edge mucked with the optimization strategy.
- The functions that get called, and the depth of any recursive calls that happen. In the simplest case, the generated JS could detect which browser it's running in and behave differently. It's also conceivable that the size of the window plays a role, e.g. if code iterates over every pixel of a dynamically-sized canvas; or things that have been stored in the profile (`LocalStorage` etc). If you have any browser extensions installed that change what the page is doing, that could also affect things. It's impossible to rule out anything without knowing more about what the app(s) is/are doing.